# How can I show the subcategories content on the parent category page?

Tags: categories

I have a WordPress website that has a category with two subcategories.

Now, how is it possible to show the content (the subcategories items/content) on the parent category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```
<?php 
    $sub_cats = get_categories('parent=' . get_query_var('cat'));
    if( $sub_cats ) :
        foreach( $sub_cats as $sub_cat ) :
            $sub_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'category__in' => array( $sub_cat->term_id ),
                'posts_per_page' => -1)
            );
            if ( $sub_query->have_posts() ) :
                while( $sub_query->have_posts() ) : $sub_query->the_post();
                    //your output//
                endwhile;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn't do the trick. Im not sure if you know what I mean. I would like to have a parent category, with its subcategory titles listed. Under each subcategory title I want the content related to that specific subcategory. I know its complicated :) sorry

Comment: the code is meant to go into category.php; if you need to show the parent category, add the new code after the existing loop. what are you using as `//your output//` ? what is the output of the suggested code? how you style the output with html tags and css, is your problem. can you paste the full code of your category template into a pastebin.com and post the link to it here?

Comment: In what way does this not work @Bagger? @Michael's answer sets up the query for you, you just need to fill in what you want it to display...

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with output? Do I have to put in <?php or just normal html?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cBh7tD5S here is my code

Comment: I don't know how to fill in the output area? can you show me an example. Thanks you a million! :)

Comment: the clean code is here. Please help me.... http://pastebin.com/py2hrawQ where and how do I put the code you showed me?

Answer (score 1):

```
$cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query'   => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category', //may be categories, I never remember, try both
            'field'    => 'slug', //may need to use ID, depends on output
            'terms'    => $cat
            //children are included by default
        )
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That will give you an array of post objects. You can use [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) to feed that into a loop if you want. This code will be expansible as you add subcategories they will be queried as well.

Docs: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)

## update

```
<?php
$cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query'   => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category', //may be categories, I never remember, try both
            'field'    => 'id', //may need to use slug, depends on output
            'terms'    => $cat
            //children are included by default
        )
    )
);  
$my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $my_posts->have_posts()) : while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post(); ?>     
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="entryCategory">              
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignright' ) ); ?></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: how do I do that setup_postdata() as you mention?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about which part of the documentation on it (that I linked in my answer) you do not understand?

Comment: when I add the code from you @ m0r7if3r I get this on my web: http://www.graaecopenhagen.com.tmp2.franklyweb.dk/graae/category/belts/

Comment: change `field` to `id` and see if that fixes anything. That error probably isn't being caused by my code...not directly at least. A bit of context for the code would be more than helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: it doesn't change anything to change field to id. the code is here:  
http://www.pastebin.com/cBh7tD5S

Comment: Try changing `$posts` to anything else...something like `$my_posts` would be fine. That code you posted a link to is a complete mess, you should really read up on the [Wordpress coding standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards), especially if you're gonna be asking for people to review your code for errors. I do not see my code in there, so I cannot diagnose your error(s).

Comment: sorry about that mate.. http://pastebin.com/CFQrNWfN here you go! :)

Comment: I updated the code. Copy paste EXACTLY what is there, I assume you properly close out the loop, but that was not included. Starts at line 20 of your pastie.

Comment: what code do you want me to copy paste? awesome if you found out how to solve the problem!

Comment: The update in my solution.

Comment: it looks like the same mate.. I have put in your updated code, and nothing has changed..? hmm?

Comment: To make it easy for you, have a look at this: http://www.graaecopenhagen.com.tmp2.franklyweb.dk/graae/category/belts/ the two belts belongs to each of the two subcategories "Casual wear" and "Formal wear" - I want the pictures that you see underneath the subcategory that it belongs to.

Comment: I made a brain fart, try it now. The major change I made over your original code is that I made `have_posts()`, etc into `$my_posts->have_posts()`

Comment: Still the same... :/

Comment: its like the content of each subcategory that I want to display on the parent category.. do you know what I mean?

Comment: Not even a little bit. Are you trying to separate them by subcategory? I don't quite understand your aims at this point.

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything. but check this put mate: I want the subcategories to be displayed on the parent category page, like this: http://www.graaecopenhagen.com/belts.aspx

Comment: So you want to have it separated out by categories then? If that's the case, Michael's solution above is the way to go.

Comment: I don't know how to fill in the output area in Michaels code? can you show me an example. Thank you a million! :)

Comment: the clean code is here. Please help me.... http://pastebin.com/py2hrawQ where and how do I put the code you showed me?